# What is the purpose of random variable functions within probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

*This is a rewrite of the question. See the original [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/141776/1).*

For a given probability field $(\Omega, A, P)$, a random variable defined on that field would be this (I'll use a real-valued random variable for simplicity):
$$X : \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$

As I understand it from the comments, this should be interpreted as this: having observed a random outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, what are the consequences of that outcome?

As an example given by Dilip Sarwate, if I toss a coin and heads comes up, I win \$1.00; if tails comes up, I lose \$0.50. In that case, the random variable would be $X(H) = 1.00,\ X(T) = -0.50$.

If I got all of the above right, here's my question. Random variables (ie. consequences of a random outcome) seem like a very high-level concept. Why are they necessary within an abstract mathematical theory such as probability theory?

Comment: You want to associate a number to each outcome. Suppose that $\Omega = \{H, T\}$ for a coin tossing experiment and you win $\$1$ if the outcome is $H$ and lose $\$0.50$ if the outcome is $T$. Your winnings (in dollars) are represented by a random variable $X$ that maps $H \to 1$ and $T \to -0.50$ whose expected value is $E[X] =1\times P(H) + (-0.50)\times P(T)$ etc.  That is the reasoning behind why the map is from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$, not the other way around.

Comment: @DilipSarwate So the purpose of $X$ is not to randomly pick a value $\omega \in \Omega$, but already given such a value, map it to a real number that, in a wordy explanation, represents the consequence of that random result?

Comment: Yes.  **You** don't get to pick the outcome of a trial of the experiment, randomly or otherwise, because nobody trusts you to pick in accordance with the probability measure already defined. You get to _observe_ the occurrence of a trial and to observe the outcome that occurred, and take actions accordingly. Note by the way that a random variable $X$ is a _fixed_ mapping; you don't get to say "The outcome is $H$; I think I will let $X$ map it to $3.1415926$ this time: tomorrow is another day."

Comment: @DilipSarwate So $X$ should be viewed as consequence. That seems like a very high-level concept. Why is it needed in the general theory?

Comment: @RahulNarain You are right.

Comment: @RahulNarain I misunderstood the purpose of a random variable. I rewrote the question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I rewrote the question.

Comment: Technically speaking, elements $\omega$ of the sample space $\Omega$ are called *outcomes* while *events* are subsets of $\Omega$. Hence $\omega$ in $\Omega$ is **not** an event, while $\{\omega\}$ may be or may not be an event, depending on the sigma-algebra under consideration.

Comment: @Didier That's right. I corrected my question.

Comment: Not quite completely, but nevermind. Let me try to summarize your question (irrespectively of whether I agree with your premises or not): (i) Probability theory is an *abstract mathematical theory* (AMT). (ii) Random variables are a *very high-level concept* (VHLC). My question: Why is it surprising that a given AMT involves some VHLCs? After all, this is exactly what AMTs are supposed to do, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Didier This is deviating a bit into a possibly never ending discussion, but I'm more of the opinion that abstract theories should deal only in abstract notions and leave high-level details to each specific application of the theory.

Comment: No deviation intended. I tried to summarize (what I could make of) your question, you might want to confirm this is what you intend to ask. With the current formulation, in view of (i)-(ii), it seems only natural to see that random variables (aka VHLCs) enter an AMT such as probability theory.

Comment: @Didier Yes, this is what I meant. What part do you think I should make clearer? :)

Comment: To suggest avoiding random variables in probability theory is analogous to suggesting that functions be avoided in analysis.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay, but why? :) (I wasn't suggestion anything, though, I was just asking.)

Comment: I think of probability as the study of random variables.

Comment: If random variables in probability theory are not abstract enough a concept, continuos function is not abstract enough a concept in measure theory.

Comment: Paul: you might want to make clearer why you rhink that the fact that some VHLCs enter an AMT requires an explanation.

Comment: @Didier It's the "very high-level" vs. "abstract" contrast that doesn't seem to fit. I don't think I understand random variables well enough yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kolmogoroff's probability axioms and the notion of random variable are a prime paradigm of $20^{\rm th}$ century mathematics. To compute probabilities connected with coins and urns you maybe could do without random variables; but if you want to go at complicated stochastic phenomena like the weather you absolutely need them.

A random variable has a priori nothing "random" about it: It is a well defined function on a maybe huge "probability space" $\Omega$. An individual point $\omega\in\Omega$ may be the possible "world weather during  24 consecutive hours" and entail information about temperature, clouds, humidity etc. at all points of the earth at all times of a day. Contrasting this ocean of possibilities a real valued random variable $T$ could be the temperature at Kennedy Airport, New York, at 12.00 p.m., on a given day. Given $\omega$, the value of $T$ is well defined, but "chance" or "fate" chooses the point $\omega$ where $T$ is evaluated. Note that it is absolutely impossible to "observe" the point $\omega\in\Omega$ in its totality, but we can observe $T$ on any given day, and we are even able to observe the function $t\mapsto T(t)$.

Kolmogoroff's axioms allow to talk coherently about the "probability that it rains on three consecutive days at Kennedy airport" or about the probability that the temperature is $\leq 31^\circ$ Celsius there at $09.00$ a.m. tomorrow, without really dealing with the intricacies of the space $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

The axioms of probability theory were designed to fit with the existing "layman's" notion of probability, i.e. the chances (a real number), of an certain event ($\omega$) occurring, from a set of given possible outcomes ($\Omega$).

In probability theory, like in most branches of mathematics - necessity is the mother of invention, not the other way round.

Comment: I never expected engineering principles to creep into math. :|

Comment: When you say this, "the chances (a real number), of an certain event (ω) occurring", are you talking about random variables? If so, isn't there already a function that does what you said, the $P$ in the field $(\Omega, A, P)$?

Comment: See my comment on the main question, regarding the use of the word *event*.

Comment: The point, I think, is that probability is not just an abstract mathematical theory invented for its own sake.  It was very much motivated by real-world problems.  And those real-world problems often involve random numerical quantities (e.g. how much do I win or lose when I play this gambling game) which are best modelled using random variables.

Answer (score 0):

Probability theory grew out of the mathematical treatment of gambling. It came to live as a very concrete subject. There are several ways to formalize probability and it is possible to formulate probability in a completely point-free way. So you dispose of the space $\Omega$ and just work with a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra of events and a probability measure defined on it. Random variables can then be defined as Boolean $\sigma$-homomorphisms. If you want to recover the points, you can take $\Omega$ to be the space of maximal consisten descriptions in terms of events (they are ultrafilters). This approach is well described and motivated in the beautiful paper [On the axiomatic treatment of probability](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm3/cm3116.pdf) (1955) by Jerzy Łoś. The cost is an additional layer of abstraction.